# Unable to start oracle install

Tags: oracle, unix

I have uninstalled 11g oracle of unix system, then trying to reinstall it. Following is error I am Trying to solve

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SgnJajm8nss/U1zsrwnsCyI/AAAAAAAAD_I/CIHz9aIYhY0/s1600/1.png

For that i did following steps

1. cat /etc/oraInst. loc
   2 CD oraInventory path>/oraInventory/ContextXML
2. VI inventory.xml
3. Remove the line that contains the new ORACLE Home. I think I did something wrong here
4. Exit and re-run the installer.

Error:INS-10012 setup driver intialization failed
java.lang.nullpointer exception

Comment: try to remove the /etc/oraInst.loc file

Comment: i am trying to rm /etc/ oraInst.loc  its not deleting ..